# Question about replacing hard drive on laptop

Tags: hard-disk

I'm trying to replace an HHD for an SSD on a " MSI CX61 2QC-1654US" but when I go online to buy for ssd they all look super big. I was doing a little research and there is something called Caddy to substitute the dvd but I don't want to go without dvds. So how can I find a ssd that fits my laptop? I uploaded a pic so you can see how small it is (m... That didn't sound right... Hahaha) anyway.. please give me a little help, I'm doing my bachelor in Computer science now but I have no idea about hardware and I'd like to learn. Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Measure the width of the HDD. If it is about 2.75 inches then it is a 2.5" HDD and so a 2.5" SSD will fit.

Some SSDs are thinner than some HDDs so they come with a spacer. Any non-electrically-conductive packing would do if you find the SSD is not held firmly, but I do not expect that to be a problem as they normally use four screws to hold them in.